# Convert list of dictionaries into separate columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to take a df that has 1 column of a list of dictionaries

Example df:

```
testData
{1: MLB, 2: NBA, 3: NFL}
```

into the following:

```
Number   Sport
1        MLB
2        NBA
3        NFL
```

I've tried the following:

```py
pd.DataFrame(df['testData'].values.tolist())
```

But this returns

```
MLB NBA NFL
1   2   3
```

I think I'm close but just need some help on how to properly transform my dataframe.

Comment: Here's a start: `pd.Series(testData).reset_index()` Now figure out how to fix the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use apply with the pd.Series constructor:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
                         testData
0  {1: 'MLB', 2: 'NBA', 3: 'NFL'}

In [12]: df["testData"].apply(pd.Series)
Out[12]:
     1    2    3
0  MLB  NBA  NFL

In [13]: df["testData"].apply(lambda d: pd.Series(list(d), d.values()))
Out[13]:
   MLB  NBA  NFL
0    1    2    3
```

---

To get these into a single sport column you can `stack`:

```
In [14]: df["testData"].apply(lambda d: pd.Series(list(d), d.values())).stack()
Out[14]:
0  MLB    1
   NBA    2
   NFL    3
dtype: int64

In [15]: res = df["testData"].apply(lambda d: pd.Series(list(d), d.values())).stack().reset_index(level=1)

In [16]: res.columns = ["sport", "number"]

In [17]: res
Out[17]:
  sport  number
0   MLB       1
0   NBA       2
0   NFL       3
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding but that is what im getting already. I would like 

Number   Sport
1        MLB
2        NBA
3        NFL

Comment: @skimchi1993 see edit, does that do it for you? Also, I'm assuming this has more rows than just one... (my code above supports that).

Comment: Hmm. im getting a "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" error. Looking into it

Comment: @skimchi1993 do you have some entries like `{1: NBA, 2: NBA}` ?

Comment: Yes. Is that not allowed?

Comment: @skimchi1993 Try this way instead: `df["testData"].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_frame`:

```
test_data = {1: 'MLB', 2: 'NBA', 3: 'NFL'}
pd.Series(test_data).to_frame('sport').reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Number'})


   Number sport
0       1   MLB
1       2   NBA
2       3   NFL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like:

```
ps = pd.Series(testData)
df = pd.DataFrame(ps).reset_index()
df.columns = ['Number', 'Sport']
```

Except this if you don't want first index column , can do like this also:

```
df.set_index('Number', inplace=True)
```

Result will be

```
Number    Sports      
1         MLB
2         NBA
3         NFL
```