# Pandas move list of titles and currency to separate columns

Tags: pandas

I have a list of products in a CSV like this:

```
Journal of Fishing,USD,1000
Journal of Fishing,GBP,1300
Journal of Fishing,EURO,1800
```

I want to use Pandas to convert it to:

```
Title,USD,GBP,EURO
Journal of Fishing,1000,1300,1800
```

Any idea on how I should go about doing that? I looked at this answer ([Convert list of dictionaries into separate columns pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248899/convert-list-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-pandas)) and it seems maybe I should be using pd.to_frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `your_file.csv` contains:

```
Journal of Fishing,USD,1000
Journal of Fishing,GBP,1300
Journal of Fishing,EURO,1800
```

Then:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", header=None)

df = df.rename(columns={0: "Title", 1: "Currency", 2: "Amount"})
df = df.pivot(index="Title", columns="Currency", values="Amount").reset_index()
df.to_csv("out.csv", index=None)
```

Creates `out.csv` with content:

```
Title,EURO,GBP,USD
Journal of Fishing,1800,1300,1000
```